# Browser autofills wrong fields in Wicket formpanel

Tags: java, wicket, autofill

I am using a Wicket formpanel to allow admins of the webapp to edit user account data. There is a password field, where an admin can set a new password for a user and other account data fields. When I open the formpanel the browser autofills the password field with MY password I saved in the browser. This field should be left blank by default. In addition the browser inserts my username ("admin") in the field for the mobile number!

[image: The formpanel]

Is there a way to avoid this behavior by changing the code of the formfield? For example prohibit autofill or something like this?
Here are the relevant code parts:

```
        mobile = new TextField<String>("mobile");
    mobile.add(PhonenumberValidator.getInstance());
    mobile.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    addToForm(new FencedFeedbackPanel("mobileCfp", mobile));
    addToForm(mobile);
    generatedPassword = new GeneratedPasswordLabelPanel("generatedPassword");
    generatedPassword.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    generatePassword = new IndicatingAjaxLink<Void>("generatePassword"){
        private static final long serialVersionUID = 6759645521399346111L;

        @Override
        public void onClick(AjaxRequestTarget target) {
            generatedPasswordString = PasswordGenerator.generatePassword(8);
            generatedPassword.setPasswordString(generatedPasswordString);
            target.add(generatedPassword);
        }
    };
    newPassword = new PasswordTextField("newPassword");
    newPassword.add(PasswordValidator.getInstance());
    newPassword.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    newPassword.setModel(new Model<String>());
    newPassword.setRequired(false);
    newPassword.setResetPassword(true);
    newPassword.add(new RequiredLabelBehavior());
    confirmPassword = new PasswordTextField("confirmPassword");
    confirmPassword.setOutputMarkupId(true);
    confirmPassword.setModel(new Model<String>());
    confirmPassword.setRequired(false);
    confirmPassword.setResetPassword(true);
    confirmPassword.add(new RequiredLabelBehavior());
    pwContainer = new WebMarkupContainer("pwContainer");
    pwContainer.add(confirmPassword);
    pwContainer.add(newPassword);
    pwContainer.add(generatePassword);
    pwContainer.add(generatedPassword);
    pwContainer.add(new FencedFeedbackPanel("newPasswordCfp", newPassword));
    pwContainer.add(new FencedFeedbackPanel("confirmPasswordCfp", confirmPassword));
    pwContainer.setVisible(ajax);
    addToForm(pwContainer);
```

And this is the Wicket-Html Code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
        <div wicket:id="emailCfp" />
        <input wicket:id="email" type="text" />
        <div class="brclear"></div>

        <select wicket:id="account.salutation" />
        <div class="brclear"></div>

        <input wicket:id="title" type="text" style="width:100px" />
        <div class="brclear" />

        <div wicket:id="firstnameCfp" />
        <input wicket:id="firstname" type="text" />
        <div class="brclear"></div>

        <div wicket:id="lastnameCfp" />
        <input wicket:id="lastname" type="text" />
        <div class="brclear"></div>

        <div wicket:id="phoneCfp" />
        <label><wicket:message key="phone" /></label><input wicket:id="phone" type="text" />
        <div class="brclear"></div>

        <div wicket:id="birthday" />
        <div class="brclear" />

        <div wicket:id="mobileCfp" />
        <label><wicket:message key="mobile" /></label><input wicket:id="mobile" type="text" />
        <div class="brclear"></div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset wicket:id="imageContainer">
        <legend><wicket:message key="legend.picture" /></legend>
        <div>
            <img style="float: left; margin: 0px 5px 5px 0px;" wicket:id="userImage" />
            <br />
            <span wicket:id="blob"></span>
        </div>
    </fieldset>

    <fieldset wicket:id="pwContainer">
        <legend><wicket:message key="legend.pw" /></legend>
        <input type="button" wicket:id="generatePassword" wicket:message="value:generatePassword" />
        <div style="float:left;">
            <div wicket:id="generatedPassword" />
        </div>
        <div class="brclear"></div>

        <div wicket:id="newPasswordCfp" />
        <input wicket:id="newPassword" type="password" />
        <div class="brclear"></div>

        <div wicket:id="confirmPasswordCfp" />
        <input wicket:id="confirmPassword" type="password" />
        <div class="brclear"></div>
    </fieldset>

    <wicket:child />

</wicket:extend>
```

Thank you!

Comment: In this case the HTML code is probably more helpful because the browser will not be able to access your java code.

I think that, the auto filled textfields will have the name="password" or "username" and are therefore automatically filled.

Comment: Accept the answer or write a comment, please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code will show you how to deactivate auto fill for a HTML form. I think that is what you need. But I do not know how to set this value in Java. `autocomplete="off"` is the magic parameter.

```
<form action="demo_form.asp" method="get" autocomplete="off">
   First name:<input type="text" name="fname"><br>
   E-mail: <input type="email" name="email"><br>
   <input type="submit">
</form>
```

**Edit:** I found something at https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/WICKET-1504, but I'm not sure if it works. 
`newPassword.put("autocomplete", "off");`
and the same for the username input field object.

Comment: To achieve this, you need to use `newPassword.add( AttributeModifier.replace("autocomplete", "off") )` (Wicket 6, a bit different in Wicket 1.5)